# RegisterStartupScript Alert Error when carriage return is in the string

Tags: c#, registerstartupscript

I have RegisterStartupScript in the code-behind class to alert error message -- it works fine except when the error has line feeds or carriage returns (I think).  Here is the snippet:

The commented code works fine!

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //Page.ClientScript.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Failure", "alert('ERROR: '), true);
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "System Error", "alert('" + ex.Message.Replace("'", "\\'") + "');", true);
        }
```

Comment: So, i am not sure i understand this question.  You are saying that your error errors out?

Comment: the alert message never shows up.

Comment: Please read on ["SQL injection"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - it applies to many languages/conditions (including yours) - strings provided by user/external entity can't be placed into scripts without proper encoding or better yet language specific mechanism to pass text values.

Answer (score 0):

Line terminators are not allowed in js strings.
Eliminate the line terminators (carriage returns, new line symbols etc.) using regular expressions:

```
var errorMsg = Regex.Replace(ex.Message, 
    @"[\u000A|\u000D|\u2029\u2028|\u000D\u000A]", " ");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "System Error", 
    String.Format("alert('{0}');", errorMsg), true);
```

Comment: I tried this, and still did not work -- the alert never comes up - However, as a test, if I hard code the errorMsg value to a regular string, the alert does come up!

Comment: You should try launching a firebug and inspect for the specific js error. Also in debug mode try to copy a value of ex.Message property and inspect it for invalid symbols.